# CoreData fetch request NSPredicate not working

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I've added a new bool property to an entity in my CoreData model and migrated the existing data to the new model. I now want to fetch only the data with a bool value of `false`. I tried everything suggested here on StackOverflow but I could not find an answer to my problem.

I tried following predicates:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %i", #keyPath(Tag.isWrite), false)
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isWrite == 0")
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isWrite == %@", NSNumber(value: false))
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

The default value for the migrated model is `false` for `isWrite`. When I don't apply the predicate and set a breakpoint before displaying my data I can clearly see that `isWrite` is false in the debugger. When I apply the predicate I don't get any data.

Am I missing something out?

Comment: I have seen previous questions (which I can’t now find) which imply that there is some problem in CoreData with attribute names that begin “is...”.  Might be worth trying a different name for your attribute.

Comment: Omg yes, it works! How stupid is that. Thanks! Post this as an answer and I'll accept that and give you an upvote..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be a problem in CoreData with attribute names beginning with “is...”.  Try changing the name for your attribute.